How to not destroy my opensearch domain when performing 'terraform destroy'?
I have created many different AWS resources with terraform such as ECS, VPC, EC2, opensearch...
I'm in a debugging phase and I need to frequently create/destroy dozens of resources besides opensearch (I don't want to destroy opensearch because it's very slow to create/delete)
I used "terraform state rm " to remove opensearch from state management, but it associated a security group:
resource "aws_security_group" "opensearch" {
  name   = "${terraform.workspace}-opensearch"
  vpc_id = local.vpc_id
}

I used "terraform state rm " again to remove this sg from state, but after that when I run terraform apply, terraform still seems to be trying to create this sg:
Error: creating Security Group (default-opensearch): InvalidGroup.Duplicate: The security group 'default-opensearch' already exists for VPC 'xxxxx'


Well, you could instead do a terraform import for the SG. It's a single command and could be the easiest way of iterating faster during the development phase.

There is feature request for this: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/2253 ... just like we have -target= to just do actions on a specific resource there should be something to do the opposite, seems the solution will be -defer=

I use three or four separate deployments with their own code directories and their own state files, categorized by how often I might want/need to create and destroy the objects and the relative cost of recreating them.

setup - things that need set up before everything else: e.g. SES, VPC, secrets
database: databases and their ancillary resources. Database might take ten minutes to create but could take hours/days to reload.
storage: s3 buckets, EFS. Ephemeral-ish, can rapidly recreate but would be annoying and often unnecessary.
application: everything else.

If I need the results of one apply as input to the next, I'll either use a resource's data block, or a terraform_remote_state data block.
